# How to typeset the name of a category?

Tags: fonts, bold

I'm LaTeXing some category theory, and typeset the names of my categories in boldface (**Set**, **Rel**, ...). Since I might want to change that, I put

```
\newcommand{\catname}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\catname{Set}}
\newcommand{\Rel}{\catname{Rel}}
...
```

in my document header. But `textbf` very kindly respects the italics elsewhere in the document, so that if I try to typeset a category inside a definition (say) I get ***Set***. I don't want this -- I'd like the categories to be upright.

I tried

```
\newcommand{\catname}[1]{{\bf #1}}
\newcommand{\catname}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\operatorname{#1}}}}
```

but these both ruin the spacing after the category name. Help! =)

Comment: Any suggestion for the change in requirements since my answer was unaccepted?

Comment: @Werner I realised that your answer, though correct, doesn't actually solve the problem, because the problem isn't where I thought it was. (LaTeX doesn't get the spacing right around `\ensuremath`s, I think. I can try to make an MWE if you'd like.) I'm putting together an answer/update now, but it's hard to extract the bug from the several-thousand lines of dissertation =p

Comment: You can reformat the spacing using elements like `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathord`, etc. However, the problem spacing has to be visualized (via code/picture) in order to find the best solution.

Comment: @Werner I'll ask a new question, so you have the accept again =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap it in a group and add `\normalfont` to it; this will localize the font change initiated by `\normalfont`. This way it will revert back to the default before setting it in **bold**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\catname}[1]{{\normalfont\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\catname{Set}}
\newcommand{\Rel}{\catname{Rel}}
\begin{document}
Here is \Set. \par
\itshape Here is \Set. \par
\sffamily Here is \Set.
\end{document}
```

If you wish to maintain the current font family as well yet only print it upright, use

```
\newcommand{\catname}[1]{\upshape{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Note the difference in the last entry when using the above definition:

[image]

Comment: Why not `\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}`? However I definitely prefer `\mathbf` since this is math.

Answer (score 10):

Replacing `\textbf` by `\mathbf` seems to work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\catname}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \emph{\dots in the category $\catname{Set}$.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: True -- but only in math mode! =)

Comment: @katrielalex The name of a category *is* math.

Comment: This approach makes it simpler to keep the coherence of the fonts in the file, since changing `mathbf` to a different font will also change the font of your categories, and all other symbols you decided should share the same bold font without altering the bold font outside the math environment.

Comment: @GustavoJasso Oh, I agree -- I definitely don't think changing `mathbf` would be a good idea. I'm not sure why I think of category names as non-math... I may have been doing this too long!

Comment: @katrielalex I don't understand your comment, do you mean textbf?

Comment: @GustavoJasso oh, I misread your previous comment :$

Comment: My point is the font family used by `\mathbf` is different from the bold face used outside the math environment. Thus you gain some flexibility for changing fonts here and there.